# How to see Valgrind Massif output (or other heap profiler) as program executes?

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory, profiler, massif

When using Valgrind Massif in LINUX, I tried to see the massif.out.pid file in real time but it produces this file after Massif finished executing. I want to place breakpoints in the code to watch the effect certain instructions have on the heap as there are only a few points of interest. I know I could rewrite some of the code to manage this but this means influencing the subject code in a way that won't be the final result as well that their is numerous programs I want to do this on. Is there a way to watch points in the code while watching the profiler profile the heap at the same time, so I can distinguish between points of execution?

Comment: You can use VS memory profiler and create heap state snapshots after hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: sorry need linux solution but your response prompted a google search from which may yield a solution to see tracking the heap as the program is running, come see my answer..thanks for the prod

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a tool in Linux that can give real time data, I haven't tried it out but found it after additional google searching. Its called heaptrack and apparently it can track the heap while the program is running:

http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-linux

Answer (score 0):

Write sleep(0.5) in the code where you want to see the memory heap usage.
then execute application with heaptrack ./app 
and then open the result file with heaptrack_gui app.heaptrack.gz

go to consumed tap and check the memory usage by time line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late, but massif-visualizer is the tool you looking for :
[massif-visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer)